# Protect our WMS map tiles to only accessible from our site

Tags: geoserver, wms, leaflet, tiles, security

We are using geoserver (2.3) to serve WMS map tiles generated from mapping data we licenced. We use leaflet on the client side to show the map (part of a ruby on rails site running on heroku). Because of the licence of the mapping data, we should not allow anybody to use these map tiles, it should be only accessible by our users when they are using the map on our website.

Is there any way to avoid somebody just taking the WMS URL from our javascript code and using it on another site?
Or bulk downloading all the map tiles?

We can configure the geoserver to require username/password or certificate, but then we would need to expose it to the client side.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at these questions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=WMS+password+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Hi! Thanks, yes, I've looked at these, but I didn't really get what we needed. But I'll read them again, maybe I missed something.

Comment: This question should provide useful leads: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5686

Comment: Thanks! So reading through all this, it seems like the best solution would be to proxy the WMS requests through our web server so we can rely on the user session to only serve our authenticated users. Does that sound right?

Comment: That is correct.